# Is there a emacs valgrind interface?

Tags: emacs, elisp, valgrind

I was wondering if there is a reliable emacs interface for valgrind and its different tools?
I have searched and sadly not found anything.

It would be interesting to have something to jump to the concerning lines via memcheck.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compilation mode has regexps for this.  You may like compilation-shell-minor-mode as well.

Comment: Thanks, do you eventually know of any emacs interface for the other valgrind tools like callgrind?

Comment: I don't.  I would check the Emacs wiki though.